# Hapi server with basic Authentication and Angular2

Tags: angular, authentication, hapi.js

I'm new in angular and in Hapi.
I would like to create a server and an app with just a simple login page.
The user can log in and then he can access to some other pages.

So far, I have a Hapi server using hapi-auth-basic scheme authentication

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('Hapi');

const users = {
    john: {
        username: 'john',
        password: '$2a$10$iqJSHD.BGr0E2IxQwYgJmeP3NvhPrXAeLSaGCj6IR/XU5QtjVu5Tm'   // 'secret'
    }
};

const validate = async (request, username, password, h) => {
    const user = users[username];
    if (!user) {
        return { credentials: null, isValid: false };
    }

    const isValid = await Bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    const credentials = { id: user.id, name: user.name };

    return { isValid, credentials };
};

const main = async () => {

    const server = new Hapi.Server({ 
        port: 3000,
        host: 'localhost',
        routes: { cors: true },
        debug: { request: ['*'] }
    });

    await server.register([
        require('hapi-auth-basic')
    ]);

    server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', { validate });
    server.auth.default('simple');

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/authenticate',
        handler: function (request, h) {
             return 'welcome';
        }
    });

    await server.start();
    return server;
};

main()
.then((server) => console.log(`Server listening on ${server.info.uri}`))
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

In Angular I have my login page and I like to send an authentication request to the api server.

Here is the function in auth-service.ts which call the server

```
getRequestWithBasicAuth(user: User): Observable<any> {
    let data = btoa(user.name.toLowerCase() + ':' +  user.password);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + data);

    return this.http.get(this.authenticateUrl, {headers: headers})
        .map((res: Response) => {
            let jsonObj: any;
            if (res.status === 204) {
                jsonObj = null;
            }
            else if (res.status === 500) {
                jsonObj = null;
            }
            else if (res.status === 200) {
                jsonObj = res.json()
            }
            return [{ status: res.status, json: jsonObj }]
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        });
  }
```

Hapi console log this:

```
Debug: auth, unauthenticated, missing, simple core.js:122
    Error: Unauthorized
```

I couldn't find any tutorial with the complete backend and frontend code.
I tried several things and I'm starting to feel that basic authentication is not really made for what I want to do. But still, if I send the credentials correctly in the headers it should work, right ?

How can I send correctly the credentials ?
I understood that with basic authentication, the user cannot logout. What kind of authentication scheme should I use ?
Do you have any recommendation about tutorial or documentation which could help me to understand all this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json Web Token(JWT)](https://jwt.io/introduction/) for login and authentication.
In angular +2 can use [this package](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) for authentication with (JWT)